# Migration to NetBeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I'm switching over from Eclipse to NetBeans for the first time, and have two quick questions I can't seem to find the answers for.

1. Is the "attachable" debugger from the Debug menu item *the* Java Debugger (**jdb**)? Or is it a NetBeans variant?
2. In Eclipse there is an INI file where I can specify arguments and do things let dictate how much RAM Eclipse will consume when launched. Is there a similar file for NetBeans, or menu/dialog within NetBeans?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re 1: I'm pretty sure it's the java debugger from currently selected Java Platform.

Re 2: Look for `netbeans.conf` file in NB installation directory.